# Problem with mdframed, lstlisting and subfig

Tags: tikz-pgf, listings, mdframed

I'm trying to understand why the following code does not compile.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstnewenvironment{lstframed}
{
    \mdframed[backgroundcolor=LightSlateGray!10] }
{
    \endmdframed
}

\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \subfloat[A]{
        B
    } \\
    \subfloat[C]{
        \begin{lstframed}
            D
        \end{lstframed}
    }
    \caption{E}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

If I do not use `mdframed`, then everything is fine, but I'm using a fancy frame in my real document, so I really need it.

Comment: May be you should switch to a better tool. Migrate to `tcolorbox` that has listings support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to put verbatim material in the argument of a command (`\subfloat`) and this has severe limitations, as you've experienced. One option would be to previously box the listing material:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{subfig}

\lstnewenvironment{lstframed}
  {
    \mdframed[backgroundcolor=LightSlateGray!50]
  }
  {
    \endmdframed
  }

\newsavebox\mybox

\begin{document}

\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{lstframed}
Some test code
\end{lstframed}
\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \subfloat[Caption for the first subfloat]{%
    \rule{5cm}{2cm}%
    } \par
    \subfloat[Caption for the second subfloat]{%
    \usebox\mybox%
    }
    \caption{E}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another approach here would be to use the [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package instead, since it offers out of the box support for the `listings` package. In any case, since you are going to place verbatim material inside the argument of `\subfloat` you'll need the previous boxing:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\usepackage{subfig}

\newtcblisting{lstframed}{
  colback=LightGray!50,
  listing only
}

\newsavebox\mybox

\begin{document}

\begin{lrbox}{\mybox}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{lstframed}
Some test code
\end{lstframed}
\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \subfloat[Caption for the first subfloat]{%
    \rule{5cm}{2cm}%
    } \par
    \subfloat[Caption for the second subfloat]{%
    \usebox\mybox%
    }
    \caption{E}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]